# Why is there an error with this simple Excel formula using MOD and ROW()

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to set up alternating row styling on a selection.  I click on the first row and drag down to row 145 (where data ends).

Then I go into Conditional Formatting, choose new rule, and am trying to enter this formula:

```
=MOD(ROW(),2)=0
```

When I click OK, I get this not very helpful error in Excel 2016:

```
There's a problem with this formula. 
Not trying to type a formula? When the first character is 
an equal (=) or minus (-) sign, Excel thinks it's a formula.
<snip>
```

What is wrong with the formula?

Comment: The formula works for me in excel 2013, without problem.

Comment: Maybe if you told us what you were hoping the formula would do?

Comment: Really silly, but copy and paste this in, see if it works: `=MOD(ROW(),2)=0`

Comment: @alwayssummer: As I wrote, I'm trying to set up alternating row styling. The formula uses the MOD function to test whether we're on an even-numbered or an odd-numbered row.

Comment: If BruceWayne's suggestion doesn't work out, try omitting the "=0" and doing an integer test rather than a Boolean test in your conditional formatting rule.

Comment: Which version if Excel are you using?

Comment: The formula works for me in excel 2016, without problem

Comment: Works for me in Excel 2007, copy and pasted from your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the `=0` part and it should work.

When you are creating the rule, choose the `Use a formula to determine which cells to format` option, then input the following as the formula:

```
=MOD(ROW(),2)
```

If you want to format the other set of rows, use the following:

```
=MOD(ROW(),2)-1
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Sorry for the delay, I was unable to log in properly for  some reason. I don't see a button to accept the answer.

Comment: It did not work to me

Answer (score 7):

Try to use ";" instead of "," before number.

**Background:** Some locales use a *"List separator"* character that is not the comma character. If you are outside the US, this might be the case for you.

**Details here:** http://datapigtechnologies.com/blog/index.php/why-your-version-of-excel-only-accept-semicolons-in-formulas-instead-of-commas/

Comment: Please give more information in order to help OP